# Скрыть блок навигации для lightSlighter

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, gallery

Как скрыть блок навигации (в нижней части картинки - точки) для lightSlider, чтобы остались одни картинки. Стандартного параметра в документации не нашел

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pager   boolean true    Enable pager option - укажите false.

```
$('#responsive').lightSlider({
    pager: false
})
```